# Have parent class use child class in static method in Node JS?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have these two subclasses:

**Male.js**

```
var Person = require('./Person.js');

class Male extends Person {
    ...
}

module.exports = Male;
```

**Female.js**

```
var Person = require('./Person.js');

class Female extends Person {
    ...
}

module.exports = Female;
```

And finally I have this base class:

**Person.js**

```
class Person {

    static makePersonBySettings(settings) {
        var person;

        if(settings.gender == 'male') {
            person = new Male(settings.name);
        }
        else if(settings.gender == 'female') {
            person = new Female(settings.name);
        }

        return person;
    }

}

module.exports = Person;
```

Parent's static method depends on knowing what the Male and Female classes are. I can't do `require('./Male.js');` at the top of Person.js because Male depends on Person.

Objective-C, Java, and more allow you to do this as the issue is resolved by the compiler.

What's the best way to resolve this issue with Node JS?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably best to use the [Factory pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/factory-method-design-pattern), like this:

```
function Maternity{
    this.giveBirthTo = function(settings){
        var person;
        if(settings.gender == 'male') {
            person = new Male(settings.name);
        }
        else if(settings.gender == 'female') {
            person = new Female(settings.name);
        }

        return person;
    }
}
```

then, later in code:

```
var factory = new Maternity();
var john = factory.giveBirthTo({name: 'John', gender:'male'});
```

Comment: I like that, better to have factory than factory method on base class

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `makePersonBySettings()` is a function that allows the user to create a `Male` of `Female` instance without direct access to those classes. And I think you want to have Male, Female, and Person in separate files. This is a bit of an unusual pattern in Node. However, if you want to follow this pattern, you can do this:

Define your Person class, but leave out `makePersonBySettings()` for now.

```
// person-base.js
'use strict';

class Person { ... }

module.exports = Person;
```

Define your Male and Female classes; require Person at the top of each.

```
// female.js
'use strict';

var Person = require('./person-base');

class Female extends Person { ... }

module.exports = Female;
```

In a separate file, require your Male, Female, and Person files, and now add your static method, like so:

```
// person.js
'use strict';

var Person = require('./person-base');
var Male = require('./male');
var Female = require('./female');

Person.makePersonBySettings = function() {
  // You can reference Male and Female here.
};

module.exports = Person;
```

And now you can `require('./person.js')` whenever you need it.

I think, though, you would do better to consider the factory pattern mentioned by [@TudorConstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35561024/4311245), unless that is completely off the table for some reason.

Comment: You can do it without the extra class: `var Person = module.exports = class{}`;